# Can AWS RDS services run on hardware hosts dedicated to a single customer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS offers the option to run VMs on hardware hosts that are dedicated to a single customer (for compliance purposes, added security, etc).

This is available when using their [Amazon EC2 Dedicated Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/dedicated-instances/)

My question is: Do they offer similar **hardware-level single-tenancy** in their managed DB services ? (AWS RDS. For example using Oracle, or MySQL)

I looked for that option but cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Side-question: *WHY* are you seeking dedicated tenancy? Often, the reasons do not actually require dedicated tenancy.

Answer (score 3):

To run RDS on dedicated hardware, you need to [create a dedicated VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html#creatingdedicatedvpc)  and then launch the RDS instance into that VPC. You also need to choose a DB instance class that is an approved EC2 dedicated instance type e.g. db.m3.medium.

For more, see [Working with a DB Instance in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#Overview.RDSVPC.Create).